# Function permitted to be run by admin only in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have created a function for updating my model in Django 1.6, the function is working but I want to restrict it to be used by admin only (i.e. after logging in as administrator).

I tried something at `url.py` like:

```
url(r'^admin/dummyfx', 'dummy.views.dummyfx'),
```

But this is not working, the link don't ask for authentication before running it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It should wrapped inside a admin.site.admin_view.

```
from django.contrib.admin.site import admin_view
url(r'^admin/dummyfx', admin_view('dummy.views.dummyfx')),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use user_passes_test decorator for your view [user_passes_test Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)

Something like that:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def my_view(request):
     ...................
     ....................
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be OK when I am already logged in to my admin account, but it should a `page not found` error when I logged out and try to access the page, the request URL is something like: `http://www.example.com/accounts/login/?next=/foo/`, how can I activate the `/accounts/login/` page?